# Batch processing of GDALWARP in FWtools

Tags: gdal, modis

I am using FWtools for pre processing of time-series MODIS data, I want to mosaic series of two scenes but I don't know the batch code for gdalwarp.

I am using Windows.

Answer (score 3):

It is not completely clear to me what you are trying to do, but if you simply want to mosaic two images using gdalwarp, this should work:

`gdalwarp input1.tif input2.tif output.tiff`

If your data is in one of the FAST formats, GDAL can handle the conversion too.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to mosaic two tiles, you can use gdalwarp. Another option is to build a VRT (virtual dataset) that does the temporal stacking *AND* the mosaicking. You can either convert the resulting VRT to say a GeoTIFF, or if you are using GDAL-aware tools, use it as a normal raster dataset.